# delayed_job not executing properly a koala job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, delayed-job, koala

I have a method using koala that fetches all the contacts of a user that has signed up to my app through facebook.

If I run it "live", it works. However it takes a long time, so I delayed it.

Thing is, when running it with delayed_job, it only retrieves one contact, instead of the full list.

Anyone has run into this issue before?

Here is the code

In Sessions#create

```
  service = Service.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  service.delay.get_contacts if Rails.env.production?
```

the get_contacts function in service.rb

```
def get_contacts(network_size = 10)
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token).get_connections("me", "friends")
  saved_contacts = user.friendships.count - 1
  total_contacts = @graph.count
  if total_contacts - saved_contacts > 0
    connections = @graph[saved_contacts..-1]
  else
    connections = nil
  end
  if !connections.nil?
    connections.each do |hash|
      Service.where(:provider => 'facebook', :uid => hash['id']).first_or_initialize.tap do |contact|
      contact.provider = 'facebook'
      contact.uid = hash['id']
      contact.save!
      Relationship.where(:user_id => user, :contact_id => contact).first_or_create
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You may browse `log/delayed_job.log` and check if everything's ok.

Comment: 2012-11-20T00:56:03+0100: [Worker(delayed_job host:pc12.home pid:16837)] Starting job worker
    2012-11-20T00:56:05+0100: [Worker(delayed_job host:pc12.home pid:16837)] Service#get_contacts completed after 2.1475
    2012-11-20T00:56:05+0100: [Worker(delayed_job host:pc12.home pid:16837)] 1 jobs processed at 0.4539 j/s, 0 failed ...